# Convert multidimensional java array list to string, store and restore

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am building a program that randomly generates multidimensional list arrays of the type :

`ArrayList(ArrayList(ArrayList(String)));`

My challenge is to find a way to save and restore these array lists once they have been (randomly) generated. I believe one solution is to convert them to a string and restore the array from that string although I can't seem to find a way to do so (I tried Json and deepToString). Please let me know if anyone has an idea. Thanks.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

//GEREATE MAP

        GenMap();
        jsonmaps = gson.toJson(maps);
    } else {
        maps = gson.fromJson(jsonmaps, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>>() {
        }.getType());
    }

//LAYOUT MAP

    MapLayout();
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    jsonmaps = savedInstanceState.getString("Sjsonmaps");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("Sjsonmaps", jsonmaps);

}
```

Comment: Why "Serializing to JSON" didn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

The following program shows converting multidimensional array to jsonString and restore back to multidimensional array using same jsonString. 
You can also store converted json String and restore back when required.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> maps = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<String> list10 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list10.add("str10");
    list10.add("str11");
    list10.add("str12");

    ArrayList<String> list11 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list11.add("str20");
    list11.add("str22");
    list11.add("str23");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list20 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    list20.add(list10);
    list20.add(list11);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list21 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    ArrayList<String> list13 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list13.add("str30");
    list13.add("str31");
    list13.add("str32");

    list21.add(list13);

    maps.add(list20);
    maps.add(list21);

    String jsonString = gson.toJson(maps);
    System.out.println(jsonString);  // maps is converted to jsonString
    // converted value is [[["str10","str11","str12"],["str20","str22","str23"]],[["str30","str31","str32"]]]

    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> genratedMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>>() {}.getType());

    System.out.println("genratedMap : " + genratedMap); // jsonString restored back to maps (ArrayList)
}
```

Note: In above program i have used Gson Library - https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Thanks, gson seems like an elegant solution to what im looking to do. I tried to implement it with a save/restore approach but it stills seem to generate the map randomly (running the GenMap void) every time i open the activity. Any ideas as to what that might be (ive pasted the code above)?Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard serialization, since `ArrayList` and `String` are serializable.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<>();

    obj.add("Hello");

    System.out.println(obj);

    /* Writing */
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myFile"));
    oos.writeObject(obj);

    oos.close();

    /* Reading */
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myFile"));
    ArrayList<String> obj2 = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();

    ois.close();

    System.out.println(obj2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried to implement the I/O Streams but i'm still cant store the randomly generated maps (see code above), anything im doing wrong?

Comment: @You're reading the maps but not storing them. You've created a new local variable that hides your field. In the ```else``` block, remove the ```ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>``` before ```maps```.